# Academic research laboratories

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset containing academic research labs with as many following fields as possible:

- Location
- Field
- Name of the head
- Number of research scientists, post-docs, PhD students, SM students, and undergrads.

I'm mostly interested in the US and computer science.

Answer (score 1):

[image: DOE and NNSA lab locations]

[Master List of FFRDCs](https://www.nsf.gov/statistics/ffrdclist/archive/ffrdc_2017.xlsx) from the NSF.

[Survey of Federal Funds for Research and Development](https://www.nsf.gov/statistics/srvyfedfunds/#sd)

> The survey provides data on federal obligations by the following key variables:
>
> - Federal agency
> - Federally funded research and development centers (FFRDCs)
> - Field of science and engineering
> - Geographic location (within the United States and by foreign country or economy)
> - Performer (type of organization doing the work)
> - R&D plant
> - Type of R&D